# What's the difference between subtyping and inheritance?

Tags: object-oriented

In object-oriented programming, I have learned the concept of `subtyping` and `inheritance`.
I thought they're the same thing, in the beginning. But I was told that they're totally different.

So what's there difference? What's there relationship?

Comment: See discussion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592131/what-is-the-difference-between-subtyping-and-inheritance-in-oo-programming as well as https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/10620/how-does-inheritance-differ-from-subtyping as well as [Inheritance Is Subtyping](https://www.cs.rice.edu/~javaplt/papers/Inheritance.pdf) as well as [Inheritance Is Not Subtyping](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.102.8635&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: Oh it's already answered in StackOverflow. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following discussions in other stack exchange groups.

See discussion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592131/what-is-the-difference-between-subtyping-and-inheritance-in-oo-programming

Also see https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/10620/how-does-inheritance-differ-from-subtyping

However there is some differences of opinion. See [Inheritance Is Subtyping](https://www.cs.rice.edu/%7Ejavaplt/papers/Inheritance.pdf) as well as [Inheritance Is Not Subtyping](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/doc_view/pid/a8507025bfa3b29d1efee53011d6ae4d76f4c325)